# Permission error when extracting a zip file to /usr/bin/ in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

This is my code:

```yaml
- name: Extract terraform into /usr/bin/
  unarchive:
    src: ~/terraform_0.15.4_linux_amd64.zip
    dest: /usr/bin/
  become: yes
```

I am getting this error:

> "Failed to get information on remote file (/usr/bin/): sudo: a password is required\n"}

I thought by using `'become: yes'`, I would have sudo access.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Your error is:

```
sudo: a password is required
```

Are you providing the `sudo` password somewhere in order to use `become: yes` ? If not, then how will `ansible` figure out the password to escalate the privilege ?

Here are few options you may use:

**Option-1:** You can supply the `become` password using command line switch as below to prompt the password at the beginning of the playbook execution.Use this option, if you do not wish to store the become password in any of the file.

```
--ask-become-pass #OR   
-k
```

**Option-2:** if you want to keep your solution touch-less(without prompt) you can set the following variable in your inventory. **One important note**, if you will be using this approach then your password will be exposed as a plain text. To prevent this, you may `vault` your password, but you will have to use `yaml` format inventory file, `ini` inventory does not support vaulted passwords.

```
ansible_sudo_pass
```

**Option-3:** Perhaps, the best solution is to tell your sudoers file to not prompt for the password for the user.This option is only possible when you do have permissions to change(either manually or via code) the sudoers file in the remote node.

```
visudo #run this from root user.
remote-user-name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```